# Why XMM register width is 128-bit while double precision floating point is 64-bit?

Tags: cpu, floating-point

As far as I know, XMM is used to store floating point. But Highest width floating point according IEEE754 standard is double precision (64-bit). But why XMM register width is 128-bit. Is another 64-bit space is wasted? If not, then what the purpose of another wasted part (another 64-bit)?

Comment: Two double precision floating point numbers, or four single precision floating point numbers, take exactly 128 bits.

Comment: An XMM register stores TWO doubles (or FOUR floats).

Comment: I was trying floating point arithmatic operation in assembly, For example addition instruction like this ```addsd xmm0, xmm1```. As you see the another operand stored in ```xmm1``` instead of in ```xmm0``` itself. That assembly piece is just basically ```|128-bit length| + |128-bit length|```.